# GWT- SingleSelectionModel celltable- how to change selected cell's CSS?

Tags: java, css, gwt, selection, celltable

I have something like the cell table here:

http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

but without this UI binder (not really sure what thats all about, my project does not use it)

Anyways, i need a way to edit the cell row selection CSS and cant find a way. Right now when i select a row it just outlines the row, i need a way to change the cells background color and edit this default behavior.

i know i can set the css for the table by using cellTable.setStyleName("mycssFile") but how do i set it for an individual cell row? I have no individual cell reference currently, and any reference i try to put in front of cellTable does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a CellTable, it grabs the default `ClientBundle` implementation (See [GWT ClientBundle for details](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html)), which adds the `cellTableKeyboardSelectedRow` CSS class name to the selected row. But ClientBundle obfuscates the class names, so it shows up as a strange alphanumeric name if you look at the source. That CSS class name is defined in `CellTable.css`, which is located in `gwt-user.jar/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.css`.

If you don't like the way it looks, you can implement your own `ClientBundle` (or extend `CellTable.Resources`) and use this constructor to make your CellTable: `public CellTable(int pageSize, Resources resources)`.

Comment: Resolved... this was most helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993918/how-do-you-change-the-mouse-over-highlighting