# how to disable mouse over highlighting of rows in celltable gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I want to disable the mouse highlighting of rows of a celltable.
This celltable is not a selectionmodel so I dont want the rows to get highlighted while mouse over event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change the mouse over highlighting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993918/how-do-you-change-the-mouse-over-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

We are basically extending the `CellTable` `Resources` which contain the `CssStyles` of the `CellTable` so that we can custom define our own css styles. for more css classes check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.css?r=8493)

```
public interface IMyResources extends CellTable.Resources {

    interface IMyStyle extends CellTable.Style {
    }

    @Override
    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "MyStyleSheet.css" })
    IMyStyle cellTableStyle();

}
```

MyStyleSheet.css CSS :

```
.hoveredRow {
  background-color: none; //or just remove this but keep the class declaration
}
```

JAVA //dont forget add the resource.

```
CellTable<dataType> myCellTable = new CellTable<dataType>(15, GWT.create(IMYResources.class));
```