# GWT CellTable - Remove the sorting arrow from a header

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to remove the sorting arrow from a header of a CellTable. (the one in the red circle below, which is from the GWT showcase : http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)

[image: arrow celltable]

But I still want the sorting capabilities of the CellTable.

Is it possible? Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untested and probably a bit of a hack, but you could try overriding the default style to return blank images.  Extend [Hilbrand's earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194877/1140456) to override the ImageResources that the CellTable uses:

```
public interface TableResources extends CellTable.Resources {
    @Source("blank.jpg")
    ImageResource cellTableSortAscending();

    @Source("blank.jpg")
    ImageResource cellTableSortDescending();
 }
```

Create 'blank.jpg' and put it in the same resources package as this interface.

Comment: Thanks! Worked as expected!

But the methods are the following :
`public ImageResource cellTableSortAscending();`
and
`public ImageResource cellTableSortDescending();`

Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: People looking for a corresponding solution for DataGrid (instead of CellTable): use the methods "public ImageResource dataGridSortAscending();" and "public ImageResource dataGridSortDescending();"

Answer (score -2):

getDataGrid().getColumnSortList().clear();

removes the sorting arrow